# Error while upgrading to Fedora 26 from 25

Tags: fedora, dist-upgrade

I'm getting this error while upgrading to Fedora 26 from 25

Detailed errors from the package manager follow:

Error running transaction: file /usr/bin/pytest from install of python2-pytest-3.1.1-1.fc26.noarch conflicts with file from python-logilab-common-0.63.2-6.fc25.noarch

Any solution?

Comment: try removing the `python-logilab-common-0.63.2-6.fc25.noarch` package before the upgrade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it's worth checking whether the package is obsolete; [in this case, it is](https://admin.fedoraproject.org/pkgdb/package/rpms/python-logilab-common/).

Assuming you're following the instructions outlined [here](https://fedoramagazine.org/upgrading-fedora-25-fedora-26/), two things you can try:

First, at step 3 from the article, append "--allowerasing", to allow the upgrade process to remove obsolete packages. I.e., instead of:

```
# dnf system-upgrade download --releasever=26
```

use:

```
# dnf system-upgrade download --releasever=26 --allowerasing
```

If that doesn't work, than second, try @DopeGhoti's solution:

```
# dnf remove python-logilab-common
```

then repeat the previous command.

Comment: BTW, the upgrade document indicates using the --allowerasing already.

Comment: True, and that's where I was drawing that from. Sorry I implied it was my addition.